# Finding Orthogonal Projection of a Sequence in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, orthogonality

> Let $S$ be the subset of $\ell^2$ consisting of all sequences $(y_k)_{k \in N}$ such that $y_k \geq 0$ for every $k$. Given $x \in \ell^2$, find the sequence $y \in S$ that is closest to $x$.

I know that the closest sequence $y \in S$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $S$, but as far as I know there is no standardised method to finding this for sequences?

It is also the solution to the optimisation problem $$ \min_y \lVert x-y \rVert$$ but this doesen't help me get much further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy if you do some guessing. Note that if $x$ is a real number then the number closest to it in $[0,\infty)$ is $0$ if $x <0$ and $x$ itself if $x \geq 0$. From this I guess that the element closest to your sequence $x$ is $y$ defined by $y_i=0$ if $x_i <0$ and $x_i$ if $x_i \geq 0$.

Now come to the proof. We have t show that $\sum (x_i-y_i)^{2} \leq \sum (x_i-z_i)^{2}$ whenever $z_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. This means  $\sum_{i
: x_i <0} x_i^{2} \leq \sum (x_i-z_i)^{2}$ whenever $z_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. For this just observe that $(x_i-z_i)^{2} \geq x_i^{2}$ whenever $x_i <0$.

Comment: How did you deduce proving $$\sum (x_i-y_i)^{2} \leq \sum (x_i-z_i)^{2}$$ whenever $z_i \geq 0$ for all $i$ is equivalent to proving $$\sum_{i
: x_i <0} x_i^{2} \leq \sum (x_i-z_i)^{2}$$ whenever $z_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. ?

Comment: That follows from the way I defined $(y_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $\ell^2$. The distance between them is
$$
\sum_n \left( x_n - y_n \right)^2.
$$
Assume, for example, that $x_1 < 0$ and $x_n \geq 0$ otherwise. Which $(y_n)$ in your set minimises the expression above? Try to generalise your observation to the case of several terms.